# laravel 4 - wrong id out of 2 id's within the routes

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-routing

I am trying to work my way with this route:

```
user/1/post/10
```

and within the posts controller (inside the show function) i try to get the $id of the post but i get the user id (1).

routes:

> Route::resource('users.posts', 'PostsController');

and here is my function within post controller:

```
public function show($id)
{
    dd($id);//output 1
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this:

```
public function show($user_id, $post_id)
{
    dd($post_id); // 10
}
```

Both parameters will be passed to child resource controller method (`show`) and the first parameter is the `parent id` and the second one is `child id`.